# Script to send email based on cell value equaling today's date

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have been trying to retrofit an old code I have used to send emails before to send an email when the formula solution in a cell equals today's date in another cell.

Here is my code:

```
function sendtest(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  var r = e.range;
  // Below is the line that selects what column to use for the send date
  var actionCol = 2;
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();
  // Testing if statement
  if (e.value == s.getRange(2, 3).getValue () && colIndex == actionCol) {
    // All rows below are used to send the email
var row = r.getRowIndex();  
    // This takes the email addresses in column D
var userEmail = s.getRange(row, 4).getValue ();  
    //The subject line of the email
var subject = "Test test " + s.getRange(row, 1).getValue ();     
    //The structure of the body of the email
var body = "It has been two weeks since test test, " + s.getRange(row, 1).getValue ();
      body +="\n\ntest test?";
      body +="\n\ntest test,";
      body +="\n\ntest test";
    // This line sends the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,subject,body);  
}
}
```

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to state what is going wrong. Every time I attempt to trigger this script (time based), I get an error telling me that line 3 (get sheet by name) is undefined.

Comment: Welcome. What is the question?

Comment: As @Rubén said, your question should include: 1.) What you're trying to accomplish (which you included, great :)) 2.) What isn't working (including any erroneous output, stack trace, etc.), and 3.) What (if anything) you've tried to fix it that hasn't worked :)

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot to mention what is wrong with the script. I added that part in an edit. I have tried several variations of the getsheetbyname and just could not get it to work. This includes getactivesheet and getsheetbyID

Comment: Have you managed to get any part of this code to run? [Time-driven event triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events) don't include `source`, `range`, or `value`. Those are all events objects of OnEdit().

Comment: I have not gotten any of it to run. I did not know there where different event triggers. Thank you!